# CakePHP 3.0 Where to put queries

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to use the new CakePHP 3.0 and I am having a bit of trouble figuring out where to put the queries.

Lets says we have something like this which is straight from their documentation.

```
$articles = $this->Articles->find('all', [
    'fields' => ['id', 'title'],
    'conditions' => [
        'OR' => ['title' => 'Cake', 'author_id' => 1],
        'published' => true
    ],
    'contain' => ['Authors'],
    'order' => ['title' => 'DESC'],
    'limit' => 10,
]);
```

Where do I put this code? In my controller class or in the model folder.

If I need to put this code in my controller class and in the future I would like to reuse this query. Do I have to rewrite the query in the other controller?

If in the model folder, which folder do I put it in? Behavior, Entity or Table? and how would I use it?

Thanks

Comment: you have to write your code in controllers only, if you want to reuse the code then you have to create components. Url : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html

Comment: Its a shame that all the database sql related code cannot be organized in the model folder only. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki that's not correct. Queries can go in controllers, but are often better placed in the model where they are more reusable.

Comment: I'd suggest that you start with reading [**the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html) (the _complete_ docs), as you seem to lack a bit of the basics. Table methods, finders, behaviors, this all can help you with reusing model related code.

Answer (score 2):

if you only use it once, you can put it in a controller action. but we like our models fat so you should put it in a method in your model (Table) for re-usability (keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

after that you can use the method in your controllers

```
$this->loadModel('Model'); //if needed
$this->Model->nameOfYourMethod();
```

Answer (score 2):

The example code you've given can be used in a controller if `$this->Articles` has been set (*e.g.* you're in the `ArticlesController`). However, in Cake it is often better to move query code to the model level where it is more reusable.

If you want to define a query method for a model you do this in the Table. For example:-

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function getAllArticles() {
        return $this->find('all', [
            'fields' => ['id', 'title'],
            'conditions' => [
                'OR' => ['title' => 'Cake', 'author_id' => 1],
                'published' => true
            ],
            'contain' => ['Authors'],
            'order' => ['title' => 'DESC'],
            'limit' => 10,
        ]);
    }
}
```

You're free to call the method what you like, just make sure it is something clear to the function of the method.

Then in your ArticlesController you can call this as:-

```
$articles = $this->Articles->getAllArticles();
```

You can call this from any controller as long as the model is loaded. For example:-

```
$this->loadModel('Articles');
$articles = $this->Articles->getAllArticles();
```

Answer (score 0):

/*
You can call this query in your controller but be sure your database must have a articles tale and authors table and articles table belongs to author table. articles table belongs author means in your articles table must have author_id.
Actually this table is joining articles table to author table and getting the result of both table according to the or,and conditions and set the limit and order 
*/